# Can not configure postgres database in GitHub actions pipeline using Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am creating pipeline for my Django Project with GitHub actions and can't make it working correctly. As I use docker, when I start the Docker and start my tests with 'python manage.py test' it works correctly. But when my tests are started I get an error. The reason is probably is that it does not know how to connect to DB, as Docker works with that in my case. I tried to use github secrets, but it seems that it does not work.

Here is the traceback in GitHub Actions:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:405: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the first PostgreSQL database instead.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Found 2 test(s).
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 400, in _nodb_cursor
    with super()._nodb_cursor() as cursor:
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 722, in _nodb_cursor
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/web-for-cyclers/web-for-cyclers/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/runner/work/web-for-cyclers/web-for-cyclers/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 24, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 68, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 1054, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 950, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 221, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 62, in create_test_db
    self._create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber, keepdb)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 199, in _create_test_db
    with self._nodb_cursor() as cursor:
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 426, in _nodb_cursor
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 269, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.4/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 196, in get_connection_params
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME or OPTIONS['service'] value.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Pipeline itself:

```
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [ 3.11 ]
    env:
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_HOST }}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_PORT }}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_USER }}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_PASSWORD }}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${{ secrets.POSTGRES_DB }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python 3.11
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        working-directory: ./backend
        run:
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Lint with flake8
        working-directory: ./backend
        run:
          flake8
      - name: Test project
        working-directory: ./backend
        run: python manage.py test
```

and project structure:

```
web-for-cyclers/

  .github/
    workflows/
      testing.yml   
    
  backend/
    core/
      __init.py__
      asgi.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
     
    static
    venv
    Dockerfile
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
    web.env
    .dockerignore
    .gitignore

 
  frontend/
    node_modules/
    public/
    src/
    .dockerignore
    Dockerfile
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    .gitignore
    

  nginx/
    Dockerfile
    nginx.conf
  docker-compose.yml
```

And docker-compose.yml:

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - backend/web.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data



  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: bash -c "./manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 core.wsgi:application --log-level debug"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - backend/web.env
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/backend
      - static_volume:/backend/static
      - media_volume:/backend/media



  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    command: serve -s /frontend/build -l 3000
    volumes:
      - react_build:/react/build
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'


  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/backend/static
      - media_volume:/backend/media
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
      - db


volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
  react_build:
  static_volume:
    driver: local 
  media_volume:
    driver: local
```

My database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT'),
        'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB')
    }
}
```